# How to remove duplicates in result query?

Tags: django

I have query:

```
articles = Article.objects.filter(Q(owner=request.user)|Q(group__user=request.user))
```

but this shows me some articles twice (owner=user and user in article editing group).

Models:

```
class ProfileGroup(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(user)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    group = models.ForeignKey(ProfileGroup)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(user)
```

How to get only non-duplicated articles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would look at distinct QS method:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

Example:

```
Article.objects.filter(whatever).distinct('id')
```

Comment: Note: doesn't work for mysql because it lacks distinct support on fields.

Comment: Oh, that's a good point. I didn't know that as I use Postgres exclusively.